# SpriteKiit Swift: touch a moving object

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a Color Sprite object which can move and bounce at the wall. How can I make it disappear when I catch it and touch it on the screen?

Comment: Tutorial, that might help: https://www.raywenderlich.com/145318/spritekit-swift-3-tutorial-beginners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set a name for your sprite like "ballNode", then in "touchesBegan" function you can handle it.

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in (touches) {
        let positionInScene = touch.location(in: self)
        let touchedNode = self.atPoint(positionInScene)
        if let name = touchedNode.name {
            if name == "ballNode" {
                //make it hidden by touchedNode.isHidden = true
                //or remove it from parent by touchedNode.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
    }
}
```