# I need to add a button to a sprite kit game

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPnKq.png)I am coding a pong game and i want to add a button to a sprite kit game that can change a value between 1 - 0.01.

I would like the add a button to do this function.
If anyone could tell me how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

I am sorry for being a noob. I'm a student.

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)
    // Check if the location of the touch is within the button's bounds
    if button.contains3 {
         print("tapped!")
    }
}
```

Thank You

Comment: that's great but what is your question?

Comment: I would like to know how to add the button i am a beginner

Comment: @DoggishtunicApps http://stackoverflow.com/a/40798803/4064189. Next time, please ask clearer question!

Comment: @MikeJSChoi tried the code... it  doesn't work.  I will ad image to the post

Comment: @DoggishtunicApps `contains3` is missing parenthesis?

Comment: @MikeJSChoi i don't think so i think i just missed some when i copied

Comment: @MikeJSChoi and the 3 is there because when i took the screenshot i did it  wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

every touches in spritekit is handle by SpriteNodes.
so if you need a button to be clicked and do something you have to add a spriteNode on the scene and in touches began method handle the touch event.
there is a complete answer for your question in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40974447/1724845)