# Need a right and left buttons to move a sprite on the x axis

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3, skspritenode

I've searched and I can only find things about making it move by swipping/dragging. I'm a beginner making a game on `Xcode` with `Sprite-Kit`, and I'm doing pretty well so far, better than expected to be honest.

But I cant seem to figure out how to make a sprite move left and right when hitting left and right buttons.  I made the left `SKSpriteNode` and right `SKSpriteNode` (I don't think that's correct) and they show up where I want obviously, but I don't know how to enable them to be touched and make the sprite move.

Sorry if this is a really amateur question, the answer will probably be obvious but I'm in a jam.

Comment: The general idea of moving sprites is to affect on their position property or their velocity vectory(sprite.physicsBody.velocity). You are directly changing position property by setting it to a new value, or indirectly using SKActions like Mina pointed. When it comes to physics,  you are directly changing velocity vector by setting it to a new value, and indirectly by applying impulses or forces to a physics body. Those are fundamentals to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of tutorials about moving sprites, begin with this [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145318/spritekit-swift-3-tutorial-beginners) tutorial.
You have to set name for your sprites and handle the movement in touchesBegan function (use this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40974447/1724845))

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in (touches) {
        let positionInScene = touch.location(in: self)
        let touchedNode = self.atPoint(positionInScene)
        if let name = touchedNode.name {
            if name == "leftButton" {
                //move to left
            }
            if name == "rightButton" {
                //move to right
               let moveAction: SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 15, y: 0, duration: 1)
               yourNode.run(moveAction)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its works until i press one the "buttons", then it instantly crashes.  im not sure where the issue is for such a simple thing

Comment: Add exception break point for better information of the crash and tell us about it

Comment: ok i got it to not crash but the player still doesnt move,  i didnt code a position for the player tho, its in the middle anchor point, not sure if thats any reason.

Comment: it will move to right 15 points whenever you touch the right button. if you want to just press the button once and player still moving it needs a little changes, tell me what do you exactly want?